# Delete extra integer when dial number in android

Tags: java, android

I need to turn +81034873845⇒+8134873845 when making call only. But i can not find any related documents based on it. What should i need to write in Google to search?Or have you any tutorial like this ?

Comment: You want to change the Number?? 8109083001700 ⇒  819083001700 .. Remove 0 after 1 ??

Comment: ya.8109083001700 ⇒ 819083001700

Comment: @SidratulMuntaha Every time you will have same type Of pattern??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own custom method for such requirement.

```
public String getPhoneNumber ( String phoneNumber )
{
     StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

     sb.append( phoneNumber.substring(0, 3) );
     sb.append( phoneNumber.substring( 4 ) );

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: @pap, Agree in that case first we have to check the Country's isd code's length. my code it part of the solution, not a full solution.

Comment: this is appreciable only for 0 in the 3rd position

Comment: Please don't use a StringBuffer when you can use a StringBuilder.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, is it mutable ? Sorry i am not aware of StringBuilder.

Comment: From the javadoc for `StringBuffer` "As of release JDK 5, this class has been supplemented with an equivalent class designed for use by a single thread, StringBuilder. The StringBuilder class should generally be used in preference to this one, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it performs no synchronization. "  That note has been there for eight years! Its a drop in replacement and StringBuffer is almost never used correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `StringBuffer` for this purpose And then **Replace** the specified character of the String with **`Null`** in  this Way:-

```
String phonenumber  = "+8109083001700"; 
StringBuffer phoneNo = new StringBuffer (phonenumber);  
int x = phoneNo.length();  
phonenumber=phoneNo.replace((x-1),3, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public String getNumber(String number)
{
  return number.replace("+810","+81");
}

String number = getNumber("+8109083001700");
```